# Log gps location requests in OS?

Tags: android, android-location, android-debug, android-os-handler

For research purposes, I want to find out how often the Facebook app retrieves info on GPS coordinates from the mobile phone.

Do you know any way to log "location requests" made by apps in Android?

Or any other methods to examine it? I can't sniff the traffic as the Facebook app runs on https.

Comment: That should not be possible, except perhaps via a custom Android ROM.

Comment: You can try and analyze the traffic using a tool like Charles proxy or (I think) Fiddler.  You will just have to install the proxy's root CA certificate on your device.  Pretty simple.

Comment: @mittmemo: The Facebook App seems to be blocking Charles proxy. I've tried, but I can't sniff the traffic.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Interesting. How would you do it with custom Android ROM?

Comment: @Kristoffer: Well, if they are using `LocationManager`, your custom ROM could have an altered `LocationManager` implementation that does your logging. If they are using the Play Services fused location API, then you probably still have problems.